# Call methods from properties

Tags: c#

Since we can declare a C# property as

```
class A
{
    private int x;
    
    public int X 
    {
        get
        {
            return x;
        }
        set
        {
            x = value;
        }

        //Create methods in here
    }
    ...
}
```

Is it possible to create methods in these properties such that you can call the method directly?

```
A a = new A();
a.X.SomeMethod();  //Do something with X
```

Instead of

```
A a = new A();
A.SomeMethod(a);
```

Comment: sure if `A.X` is a type that has a method called `SomeMethod`... - for example if you have `public string X ...` you get `a.X.Trim()` for free

Comment: why don't you give a try to see?

Comment: But here x is a primitive datatype, not a object of a custom class

Comment: Yes and that's why it's NO. unless `x` returns a type on which methid is defined you can't call.

Comment: You can call method only from its object, in your case you cannot call the method from int, what you can do is, inherit from int class and create the method inside your class and put your properties type to your new created class and call the mrhod

Comment: Or unless you also provide **extension methods** for those primitive types. Anyway I think you should explain what you are trying to do...

Comment: The way you have given an example, you can't create functions inside a getter/setter, no matter where you try and do it. You can call them, however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to create methods in these properties such that you can call the method directly?

On the one hand, yes it is possible and you can, but on the other hand, not in c#.

`Standard ECMA-335, Common Language Infrastructure (CLI)` section II.17 clearly states:

> A property can contain any number of methods in its body.

That means you can only create up to one `.get` and `.set` method, but as many `.other` methods as you like.

This example of a property called count can you find in II.17 too:

```
.class public auto autochar MyCount extends [mscorlib]System.Object { 
  .method virtual hidebysig public specialname instance int32 get_Count() { 
  // body of getter 
  } 
  .method virtual hidebysig public specialname instance void set_Count(int32 newCount) { 
  // body of setter 
  } 
  .method virtual hidebysig public instance void reset_Count() { 
  // body of refresh method 
  } 
  // the declaration of the property 
  .property int32 Count() { 
    .get instance int32 MyCount::get_Count() 
    .set instance void MyCount::set_Count(int32) 
    .other instance void MyCount::reset_Count() 
  } 
}
```

Since c# dont know the concept of `.other` methods, you will not be able to create such a method nor call it directly. Calling it is only possible through reflection.

Comment: However AFAIK without any language support those methods have nothing special at all and for sure (unless some esoteric language uses this *feature* for that) they are not supposed to extend property type. They may be used, for example, to have setters with different types (a feature C++/CLI was supposed to have, someday, but now abandoned).

Answer (score 1):

You can call method only from its `object`, in your case you cannot call the method from `int`, what you can do is, `inherit` from `int` class and create the method inside your class and put your properties type to your new created class and call the method

```
public class NewType : int
{
    public void SomeMethod()
    {

    }
}

class A
{
    private NewType x;

    public NewType X
    {
        get
        {
            return x;
        }

        set
        {
            x = value;
        }
    }
}
```

And than you can do the follow:

```
 A a = new A();
 a.X.SomeMethod();
```

Hope helps

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible *in C#*, yet the CLI specifies `.other` methods.

[Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) are used to support the OOP principle of *encapsulation*. They can be used as if they are public data members, but they are actually special methods called *accessors*.

```
public String S;
```

can be represented with a property the following:

```
public String S { get; set; }
```

This is just the short-hand version for

```
public String S { get { return s; } set { s = value; } }
```

Within `get { }` and `set { }` you can do validations, etc.

Within a property, only *get* and *set* are allowed as methods (called *accessors*)

Accessing a public member via a property

```
myVar.S // of type string
```

enable you to call all methods string allows, like

```
string sub = myVar.S.Substring(1);
```

Comment: Thank you, that explains it.

Comment: It would be possible with `Extension Methods`.

Answer (score 0):

If the return type is a built in type (and not a custom class) you can create an `Extension Method` for *all* of this type.

Try this code:

```
public class A
{
    public int X { get; set; }
}

static class Extensions
{
    public static bool IsEven(this int x)
    {
        return x%2==0;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a=new A() { X=32 };

        if (a.X.IsEven())
        {
        }
    }
}
```